# install openni_kinect failed

Tags: openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all,

When I install openni_kinect and run

```
rosinstall ~/openni_kinect PATH_TO_EXISTING_ROS_TREE 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=openni_kinect.rosinstall'
```

it shows:

```
rosinstall operating on /home/meka/openni_kinect from specifications in rosinstall files  PATH_TO_EXISTING_ROS_TREE, http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=openni_kinect.rosinstall
ahhhh error opening file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/meka/PATH_TO_EXISTING_ROS_TREE'
Usage: rosinstall PATH [<options> ...] [URI]... 

rosinstall: error: None
```

Can you help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9689/install-openni_kinect-failed/) by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2011-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to replace PATH_TO_EXISTING_ROS_TREE with a path to an existing ROS tree.

This assumes you have completed a general [ROS installation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Installation) previously.

If you're using ubuntu and have installed from debians you should use something like /opt/ros/diamondback  or if you're checking out from source you should use ~/ros.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on 2011-04-11**:
Thank you. I have completed the general ROS installation. I do not know what's wrong. But i did it again from the beginning, it worked....